# Linux Kernel Module File close not quite correct

Tags: c, linux, file, kernel-module

I have a small problem with this code. I can't figure out why it is not working.

```
static int test(const char *path)
{
    struct file *filp;
    filp = filp_open(path, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (IS_ERR(filp))
        return filp;
    // some code (only read from filp (like inode and stuff))
    filp_close(filp, NULL);
}
```

When I use this snippet once or twice or even a thousand times it works but after approximately 63000 times I run into error -23 and after that cann't open a single file. I looked up the syscalls for open and close and these use filp_open/filp_close and I just can't figure out what is wrong with this code. It must be something with the file descriptors not being deallocated, but why?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576890/enfile-file-table-overflow-when-using-kernel-iterate-dir. The problem is likely in the code you don't show (under `// some code ...`). Please, show it.

Comment: Kernel version? Other necessary information (how exactly you opened so many files)? The number much likely shows that your  code exhausted file descriptors inside kernel. But without information it's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mm_segment_t  st_old_fs;      
st_old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());

struct file *filp;
filp = file_open(path, O_RDONLY, 0);
if (IS_ERR(filp))
{
    set_fs(st_old_fs);
    return filp;
}
// some code (only read from filp (like inode and stuff))
filp_close(filp, NULL);

set_fs(st_old_fs);
```

The kernel has some special memory manager way for the file. So you need to save the old way and restore it after use the file_open.

Comment: I tried it but it did'nt work, even with none of my code in between (just the snippet). Same result: error -23

Comment: The kernel does not have "some special memory manager for the file". filp_open expects a path from userspace and if you need to pass something from kernelspace you use the set_fs stuff. I don't see how this is supposed to relate to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

file objects, like plenty others, are freed only after RCU grace period finishes. I suspect your kernel is not preemptible and you don't context switch anywhere, thus the grace period never completes and the objects accumulate. You can learn more about rcu here: https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/

The real question is what are you doing. Kernel-level work is not fit for programming beginners. If this is a college assignment, it is extremely likely you are going about it wrong or the assignment itself is just bad.